# extract and subset dictionary from pandas dataframe in correct format - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have dictionary information stored in a column in a pandas dataframe. The dataframe is set to string type. I need to extract the dictionary and subset it to create a new dictionary.

here is a command that works just fine if using a *normal* dictionary: to select specific fields from pairs to create a new dictionary

```
# initial dictionary 
dic = {'s1': [{'q': 'male','id':'1'},{'q':'female','id':'2'}], 's2' : [{'q':'employed'},{'q':'unemployed'}]}

# dic output 
{'s1': [{'q': 'male', 'id': '1'}, {'q': 'female', 'id': '2'}],
 's2': [{'q': 'employed'}, {'q': 'unemployed'}]}

# subset dictionary to first item in pair 
new_dic = {k: [x.get("q") for x in v] for k, v in dic.items()}

# new_dic output 
{'s1': ['male', 'female'], 's2': ['employed', 'unemployed']}
```

However I need to extract and produce the same output as above from a dictionary that is stored inside a dataframe, rather than the original dict. The df looks like this:

```
df_dic = pd.DataFrame({'a': [([{'q': 'male','id':'1'},{'q':'female','id':'2'}]), ([{'q': 'employed','id':'1'},{'q':'unemployed','id':'2'}]) ], 'b': ['s1', 's2']}).applymap(str)

# create dictionary from dataframe 
dic_from_df = columns = dict(zip(df_dic['b'],df_dic['a']))

# output 
{'s1': "[{'q': 'male', 'id': '1'}, {'q': 'female', 'id': '2'}]",
 's2': "[{'q': 'employed', 'id': '1'}, {'q': 'unemployed', 'id': '2'}]"}
```

Here i extract the information from the dataframe in to a dictionary which works fine (dic_from_df) - and the expected output is exactly the same as the output in new_dic. The dictionary stored inside the df is in a string format (i cannot help this - this is just the way it is due to some intermediate processing).

So when i run the same command ({k: [x.get("q") for x in v] for k, v in dic.items()}) on dic_from_df, i get the error ''str' object has no attribute 'get''...I am really stuck! Im not sure if its because it is a string, or the apostrophes (i can not strip them either..) so any comments are super welcome. thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `findall` to extract the values corresponding to the key `q` in each list of dict like strings, then using `to_dict` convert the series to dictionary

```
df_dic.set_index('b')['a'].str.findall(r"'q': '(.*?)'").to_dict()
```

---

```
{'s1': ['male', 'female'], 's2': ['employed', 'unemployed']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `ast.literal_eval()` which evaluates strings containing Python expressions.

```
new_dic = {k: [x.get("q") for x in ast.literal_eval(v)] for k, v in dic_from_df.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve your methodology, I would use the [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to deserialise the result from the dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "s1":[
      {
         "q":"male",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "q":"female",
         "id":"2"
      }
   ],
   "s2":[
      {
         "q":"employed"
      },
      {
         "q":"unemployed"
      }
   ]
})

# double quotes required for JSON
df_dic = json.loads(str(df.set_index('b')['a'].to_dict()).replace('\'', '"'))

new_dic = {k: [x.get("q") for x in v] for k, v in df_dic.items()}
```

Resulting in the desired output

```
{'s1': ['male', 'female'], 's2': ['employed', 'unemployed']}
```

The use of JSON to deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object is very common & worth noting